# How to find the number of objects in the scene with a specific component attached to it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to find the number of game objects in the scene (as an int value) that have a specific script attached to it.

for example: if there are 5 gameobjects with the script "scoreai", the int value "length" should be set to 5.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DarceVader's answer is going to be the more performant solution unless you also need to access the objects themselves.

To accomplish that, you can use

```c#
var foundObjects = Object.FindObjectsOfType<YourComponentTypeHere>();
int count = foundObjects.Length;
```

Edit: Added line to show how to actually retrieve the object count for answer completeness.

More info can be found in the Unity documentation for [Object.FindObjectsOfType()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html)

Comment: Thanks, its all good now. (originally i did try this but every time i ran the script unity crashed but for some reason, now it started working)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than doing a find on a bunch of game objects (I haven't encountered the slowness of it, but I'm told it's significant enough to only use sparingly), I'd recommend using a `static int count`, see my example below:

```
static int buildingCount = 0;

protected void Awake()
{
    buildingCount++;
    print("BuildingCound: " + buildingCount);
}
```

If your script is not a `MonoBehaviour`, put `buildingCount++;` wherever your script is initialized/starts from. Typically this is put in the constructor.